Flutter: "Share handler" plugin - Android version: When I share 4/5 files the time that passes before my app is opened is quite long, even 10 seconds
I implemented it on iOS and it works well.
As far as Android is concerned, it also works well here but has a small problem. When I share 4/5 files the time that passes before my app is opened is quite long, even 10 seconds which might make the user think there is some problem. Also sometimes a white screen appears in the meantime or other times black. Then everything works properly.
I was asking if this is normal, because on iOS there is no such wait. After all, only the path to the shared files needs to be retrieved, and I do not understand why it takes so long.
I use Flutter 3.19.6 and Dart 3.3.4
the Share handler version is 0.0.21
I have set the Manifest to share all kinds of files, both single and multiple.
Thank you in advance for any help in explaining this behaviour.
